# super and subscripts on stackrel variable

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts, stacking-symbols

How I am trying to put a label above a variable omega. That works well but I cant find a better way to have the sub- and superscripts belonging to omega itself without a gap. using the superscripts on stackrel itself places them way to high

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{eurosym,bm,amsmath}     % Mathematische Notationen
\usepackage{scalerel}

\begin{document}

$\stackrel{\scaleto{f}{5pt}}{\omega}{}^{(i)}_{kl}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

Note the use of `\,` (thinspace) to nudge the "f" superscript to the right, to improve its centering above the `\omega` character.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for \smash[t]{...} macro
\usepackage{scalerel} % for \stackrel macro
\begin{document}
$\smash[t]{\stackrel{\,\scaleto{f}{5pt}}{\omega}}^{(i)}_{kl}$
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question: Since the macro `\lstmw` will only be encountered in math mode, I'd define it as follows:

```
\newcommand{\lstmw}[3]{%
    \smash[t]{\stackrel{\scaleto{#2}{5pt}}{#1}}^{(i)}_{#3}}
```

and write `$\lstmw{\omega}{\,f}{kl}$` in the body of the document.

In fact, to make the superscript term (here: `f`) look a little bit less skinny and brittle, I'd define the macro as follows:

```
\newcommand{\lstmw}[3]{%
    \smash[t]{\stackrel{\scaleto{\scriptscriptstyle #2}{5pt}}{#1}}^{(i)}_{#3}}
```

This "works" because TeX's math glyphs are optically sized, rather than just linearly scaled versions of the "standard size" glyphs.

Comment: thanks yeah thats exactly what i was hoping for :)

Comment: I am quite new to designing my own commands, but wouldn't i create one out of this like the following: `\newcommand{\lstmw}[3]{$\smash[t]{\,\stackrel{\scaleto{ #2 }{5pt}}{ #1 }}^{(i)}_{ #3 }$}` ? Using that in math mode gets me running into missing } errors...

Comment: @Quastiat  - Please see the addendum I just posted.

Comment: thanks again that works just as expected, scaleto causes some issues with some letters but thats fine for me :)

Answer (score 3):

The `accentset` command is another possibility. By default, the accent letter is in scriptscriptstyle, but you might be interested in having it in `\scriptstyle`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}

$ \accentset{\mkern2mu\scriptstyle f}{\omega}^{(i)}_{kl}\qquad \accentset{\mkern1mu f}{\omega}^{(i)}_{kl}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the input the works as well!